# Geometry problem on angle bisectors and intersecting line segments

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

Two equal line segments $AB$ and $CD$ intersect each other at a point $M$. If the perpendicular bisectors of $AD$ and $BC$ intersect each other at the point $N$, prove that the two angles $\angle AMN$ and $\angle CMN$ are equal.

According to the following picture, here is the summary of the problem

> **Theorem**. If the following assumptions hold
>   $$\begin{align}
> AB&=CD \\
> NP &\bot AD \\
> AP &= PD \\
> NQ &\bot BC \\
> BQ &=QC \\
> \end{align}$$
>   then
>   $$\angle AMN = \angle CMN$$

[image]
**My Attempt**:
We know that the distance of every point on the perpendicular bisector from two ends of segment is equal. From that, we can know $BN = CN$ and $AN = DN$. But how can we now prove that $MN$ is the bisector of $\angle AMC$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Since same colored lines are equal in pairs, $\triangle DNC$ is congruent to $\triangle ANB$.

Result-1 $\gamma$ will be equal to $\delta$. From which, we get $\angle DAN = \angle BCN$.

Result-2 $\alpha = \beta$. This means $ADMN$ is cyclic and therefore $x = \angle DAN$.

Hope you can finish the missing detail.

Comment: How did you get that $x\cong \angle DAN$? Do you mean $y\cong \angle ADN$?

Comment: In a cyclic quadrilateral angle by producing a side equals angle in the opposite side of circle segment.