# Geometry problem on angle bisectors and externally intersecting line segments

Tags: geometry

This question is a variation of [a question by Taha Akbari, answered by Mick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805746/geometry-problem-on-angle-bisectors-and-intersecting-line-segments):

> **Theorem**. If the following assumptions hold
>   $$\begin{align}
> AB&=CD \\
> NP &\bot AD \\
> AP &= PD \\
> NQ &\bot BC \\
> BQ &=QC \\
> \end{align}$$
>   then
>   $$\angle AMN = \angle CMN$$

The original question assumed $N=AB\cap CD,P\in AD, Q\in BC$. How should the above problem be changed if the intersection between $ AB,CD$ occurs outside of them?

If the proposition is false, what  is missing in logic of such an extrapolation/ generalization? Motivation of post is to geometrically track the point $N$ by Java sketching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I would say the situation is pretty the same: $ABN$ and $CDN$ are congruent, so they are mapped into each other by a rotation with centre an $N$: that gives $\widehat{CNA}=\widehat{CMA}$, so $ACMN$ is a cyclic quadrilateral (as well as $DBMN$) and
$$ 2\widehat{CMN}=2\widehat{CAN}=\pi-\widehat{CNA}=\pi-\widehat{CMA} $$
so $MN$ is the *external* angle bisector of $\widehat{CMA}$.

Comment: Fine.The half angles at M could be also labelled.